# Найти общий объем загруженной информации приложением на c#

Tags: c#, winforms, сеть, трафик

Есть приложение winforms на c#. Иногда оно обращается с запросами к разным интернет ресурсам, получает ответы. Можно ли как-то узнать, сколько Mb было скачано за одну сессию работы с приложением. То есть мне нужно просто узнать объем траффика через мое приложение. Спасибо

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что здесь кто-то обладает экстрасенсорными способностями, сам код где ? Уважаемый.

Comment: @DigitalCore так то вопрос "как узнать объема трафика через мое приложение" имеет смысл и без кода. Хотя конкретика несомненно приветствуется (какие библиотеки используются и т.п.)

Comment: @DigitalCore, я и не требую экстрасенсорных способностей :)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, использую WebClient и все

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно использовать счетчики производительности [.NET CLR Networking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70xadeyt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Для этого необходимо включить в раздел **configuration** файла **app.config** следующий элемент:

```
<system.net>
   <settings>
      <performanceCounters enabled="true"/>
   </settings>
</system.net>
```

Счетчики позволяют получить количество байт, отправленных и полученных средствами классов .NET, для указанного процесса. Создадим вспомогательный класс:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace WinformsTest
{
    public class NetworkStats
    {
        const string CategoryName = ".NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0";//В .NET 2.0-3.5 заменить на ".NET CLR Networking"

        static PerformanceCounter _sentcounter = null;
        static PerformanceCounter _recvcounter = null;

        public static long BytesSent
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sentcounter == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Class not initialized");
                return _sentcounter.RawValue;
            }
        }

        public static long BytesReceived
        {
            get
            {
                if (_recvcounter == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Class not initialized");
                return _recvcounter.RawValue;
            }
        }

        public static bool Initialize()
        {
            //устанавливаем культуру, чтобы иметь предсказуемое имя счетчика
            CultureInfo ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            try
            {
                var category = new PerformanceCounterCategory(CategoryName);

                //для активации счетчиков нужно отправить хотя бы один запрос, неважно успешный или нет
                try
                {
                    WebClient cl = new WebClient();
                    string html = cl.DownloadString("http://example.com");
                    Debug.WriteLine(html.Length);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

                //получаем имя процесса
                Process pr = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                string prname = "";
                using (pr)
                {
                    prname = (pr.ProcessName.ToLower());
                }
                var instances = category.GetInstanceNames();

                //находим экземпляр счетчика для процесса
                string instance = "";
                foreach (string s in instances)
                {
                    if (s.ToLower().Contains(prname)) instance = s;
                }
                if (instance == "") return false;

                //создаем счетчики
                _sentcounter = new PerformanceCounter(CategoryName, "Bytes Sent", instance, true);
                _recvcounter = new PerformanceCounter(CategoryName, "Bytes Received", instance, true);
                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                //возвращаем исходную культуру
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{        
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (NetworkStats.Initialize() == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NetworkStats.Initialize failed");
            return;
        }
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    public string PerformRequest(string url)
    {
        WebClient cl = new WebClient();
        string html = cl.DownloadString(url);
        return html;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = PerformRequest("http://yandex.ru");
        MessageBox.Show(s.Substring(0,300));  
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Bytes sent: " + NetworkStats.BytesSent.ToString() +
            "; Bytes received: " + NetworkStats.BytesReceived.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!